# Close HTTP connections to apache HTTPS port

Tags: apache-2.4, https, apache2

When a client issues an http request to an apache https `VirtualHost` apache responds with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.<br />
 Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

How can I make apache close the connection or respond with an approprate ssl/tls handshake error instead?

I have a loadbalancer that learns whether a backend pool member's port is http or https by attempting to connect with http and then retrying with https. The 400 bad request error from the member traverses the loadbalancer and is returned to the client instead of causing the loadbalancer to retry with https.

Comment: My guess is that your `Apache` Web server is misconfigured.

The error you get makes me think that `Apache` tries to serve HTTPS request on its HTTP port.

Please double-check your `Apache` (virtual host ?) config.

Comment: @krisFR No, that's how it responds to `curl http://127.0.0.1:443`. It responds to `curl -k https://127.0.0.1:443` normally.

Comment: Sadly, nobody seems to know how to solve this issue. If a web admin runs an HTTPS vhost on a custom port (e.g. 4433) and a browser connects to that vhost but using http:// is there a way to tell apache to rather redirect the browser to https:// instead of displaying that error.

Answer (score 1):

I think mod_write might help: https://www.sslshopper.com/apache-redirect-http-to-https.html.

It will automatically redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS.

However, this might not work if you are using shared hosting, or don't have access to using .htaccess files.

Comment: A redirect will probably traverse the loadbalancer.